Invalid Compact JWS
I am trying to make post request but i keep getting the error:

InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS

This error occurs when I try to make a request to my backend Node.js server using the access token obtained from Auth0:
import { Auth0Provider, User } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Auth0ProviderWithNavigate = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const domain = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const redirectUri = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL;
  const audience = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_AUDIENCE;

  if (!domain || !clientId || !redirectUri || !audience) {
    throw new Error("unable to initialize auth");
  }

  const onRedirectCallback = (user?: User) => {
    console.log("User", user);
    navigate("/auth-callback");
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        audience,
      }}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithNavigate;

middleware
I have identifier key (audience on my backend and also imported it to the frontend). I still don't understand it.
import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";

export const jwtCheck = auth({
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  tokenSigningAlg: "RS256",
});`

Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this error and how to troubleshoot it effectively? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
